# What's the name of the alien which had 4 boobs?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

In *Star Wars: The Last Jedi*, we saw an alien

> on Ahch-To which had 4 human female like boobs. Luke even extracted milk from it.

What's the name of this alien animal?

Comment: I believe there were at least two aliens with 4 boobs in TLJ, wasn't there one in the Casino Night Zone?

Comment: See also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/176859/4918 "What were these animals on Ahch-To?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a [Thala-Siren](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Thala-siren), described thusly in the film's accompanying [Visual Dictionary](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_The_Visual_Dictionary)

[image]
<sub>"*Thala-sirens are large, flippered marine mammals often found sunning themselves along the coastal rocks of the island. The docile creatures are not hunted, and thus do not fear the natives of the island, but they do produce a nutritious green milk that Luke has taken to harvesting*".</sub>

Comment: Check all four slides: https://www.instagram.com/p/Bc35u0WlPYi/ (NSFW)

Comment: I was hoping it was a "moof", giving Han's insult in TFA a bit of levity here. Alas, it is not to be.