# What were these animals on Ahch-To?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

We saw a couple of mystery animals on Ahch-To. Actually most of the new species we saw from the films were on Ahch-To. We knew of Porgs before the film, with one having featured prominently in promotional material, but what were these other creatures:

### The Giant Blue Marlin thing

<sub>Click all images to embiggen, warning **low quality** when large.</sub>

[image: Blue Marlin thing Luke caught]

We see this for the first time after Luke uses the giant pole to go fishing (and I guess uses the Force to bring the fish up?)

### The Manatee-Cows-Giraffe thing

[image: Manatee-Cow-Giraffe thing Luke milks]

These creatures seem to produce a similar Blue Milk to [Bantha Milk](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Blue_milk), but whatever it was, it was unexpected

### The Mystery Sea Snake thing

[image: Mystery Sea Snake thing that breaches just behind Rey]

This creature got me excited from the get go and every other scene on Ahch-To with water in view had me looking for another one.

What were the names of these creatures?

Comment: [What's the name of the alien which had 4 boobs?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/176612/whats-the-name-of-the-alien-which-had-4-boobs/176618#176618)

Comment: @Valorum Guess that's part of the answer complete then. And the other two?

Comment: Luke doesn't use the Force on the island. It's all brute strength and muscle-memory.

Comment: @Valorum good point, my mistake.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The "*Giant Blue Marlin thing*" (that Luke is carrying) is a [**Spetan Channelfish**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Spetan_channelfish).

[image]

The "*Manatee-Cow-Giraffe thing*" is a [**Thala Siren**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Thala-siren)

[image]

The "*Mystery Sea Snake thing*" doesn't get a mention in the Visual Dictionary other than there being a brief mention of other fauna in the sea.

Comment: Do we get any more details on the Spetan Channelfish?

Comment: @Edlothiad - Just its name. We can assume that it's edible and non-sapient.

Comment: The mystery sea snake thing reminds of the creature on Degobah that ate Artoo.

Comment: Sigh. Can there be no more mysteries left in the galaxy? Oh, wait. Snoke.

Answer (score 11):

The Disney+ *Star Wars Biomes* special audio description track lists the sea serpents as [pallaskeans](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Pallaskean).

> The pallaskean was a species of sea serpent that resided in the oceans of the planet Ahch-To.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  It's great to get this finally answered; is there a more extensive description or any other information you could quote?